# Print out array of links into HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a HTML Table that I'd like to add a column of links to.

Here's my array

```
$unis = array( 
               array("title"=>"http://www.aber.ac.uk/en/"),
               array("title"=>"http://www.bangor.ac.uk/")
             );
```

I want to track through the array and print out each link. So I have two Universities in the HTML table and their respective links to appear alongside of them.

Here's my script so far but this prints out two columns with the above links for every record in the table so it looks like

```
foreach ($a as $i) {
                  echo "<tr><td><img class='uni-image' src='" . $dir . '/' . $i . "' /></td>";
                  echo "<td>" . pathinfo($i, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "</td>";
                 foreach ($unis as $row) {
                    array_map('htmlentities', $row);

                    echo "<td>" . implode($row) . "</td>";
                 }
                  echo "</tr>";
```

And the result is

```
Uni logo | Uni name | http://www.aber.ac.uk | http://www.bangor.ac.uk
Uni logo#2 | Uni name#2 | http://www.aber.ac.uk | http://www.bangor.ac.uk
```

When what I really want is

```
Uni logo | Uni name | http://www.aber.ac.uk
Uni logo#2 | Uni name#2 | http://www.bangor.ac.uk
```

Comment: Why not use this to output data: foreach ($unis as $title=>$url) {

Comment: Could you expand on this solution @BaileyHerbert with a full example?

Comment: `$a` is an array loaded with the image and university names @u_mulder

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looping over every title you will see every title for every university. Instead try:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $i) {
    echo "<tr><td><img class='uni-image' src='" . $dir . '/' . $i . "' /></td>";
    echo "<td>" . pathinfo($i, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlentities($unis[$key$]['title']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

However rather than having two arrays that happen to be in the right order I would recommend keeping the data together. I.e. perhaps have an array like:

```
$unis = array( 
    array("title"=>"http://www.aber.ac.uk/en/",'img'=>'abertayImage'),
    array("title"=>"http://www.bangor.ac.uk/",'img'=>'bangorImage')
);
```

This would simplify outputting this information together.